# Show WPF control instead of MessageBox

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms

I have a modal created for a WinForm that shows when user click the "Save" button. Instead of showing the MessageBox, I want to know if it's possible to incorporate a WPF control I've created instead? Here's my code.

```
Form frmModal = new Form();
frmModal.BackColor = Color.Black;
frmModal.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
frmModal.FormBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.None;
frmModal.Opacity = 0.6;
frmModal.Show(); //--> want to replace with WPF control
MessageBox.Show("Hello");
frmModal.Close();
frmModal.Dispose();
```

Comment: [WPF Tutorial - Using WPF In WinForms](http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/wpf-tutorial-using-wpf-in-winforms)?

Comment: don't understand why MessageBox in this example ?

Comment: @Antonio Bukula -- just an example, as I said I want to show a wpf control instead. I'm showing this code on the fly. Maybe it's a bad idea to do so. I should probably create form and show it instead of doing so. =/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you will need to bring up a new form window which uses a winform [ElementHost control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.integration.elementhost.aspx) to show the WPF control.

Comment: that's what I thought too but wanted to see if I could take a short cut.

Comment: The element host brings in/loads the WPF namespace/assembly which winforms simply does not have.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use the customized WPF control in place of MessageBox, you can have a fairly good idea how to do it by referring to this CodeProject article for details: [A Customizable WPF MessageBox](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/201894/A-Customizable-WPF-MessageBox)

Hope this is what you are looking for.